# Git: "This branch is behind" after pull request

Tags: git, github, version-control, merge, pull-request

I'm new to Git and Github. I have a repo with 2 branches: **Master** and **Develop**.

- Master is the base branch and considered the stable branch (this is the branch pulled by my webserver).
- Develop is the branch where all my latest code is in.

So after developing some new features, I created a pull request and merged the develop into the master branch. But when I select the development branch, GitHub tells me: "**This branch is 1 commit behind master.**" But why? I understand that the pull request is handled as a commit to my master branch, but the warning doesn't feel right to me.

Or to make it short: How can I bring my master branch up to date with my development branch without causing warnings/conflicts?

Thanks.

Comment: It's not a conflict, and not a wrning either. Just an information message. But you can make sure that only fast-forward merges are made by rebasing the develop branch on master, and then merge it with `--ff-only`.

Comment: Okay, I understood that '--ff-only' would solve my problem. One last question: Is there a way to do this on GitHub? My master branch is protected and to merge something into it, travis-ci checks must pass. This means I can't do it localy and then push to my origin/master.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. How can Travis get and build the software from master before you merge to master?

Comment: GitHub won't let me push to master if I enable status checks. Commits need to be made against another branch and then merged with a pull request. But this pull request can't be made without passing a status check. But I solved it: I unchecked the "Include administrators" option which forces repository owners to pass these checks, too. No I can push to the repo as always.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it clear what solved your problem:

> unchecked the "Include administrators" option

And now you was able to push as always.

Comment: Yep. Giving you the green tick for pointing it out, because I totally missed to answer it myself ;)

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question how to merge `develop` into `master` via pull request without creating the message that `develop` is now 1 commit behind `master`. @LuMa do you know the correct workflow?